# PostgreSql hstore extension with public prefix issue

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

I've struggled with my PostgreSql and hstore extension, so in my sql dump file hstore fields are created with this script:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;
```

```
CREATE TABLE public.identity_devices (
    ...
    metadata public.hstore
);
```

So I'm getting an error

```
structure.sql:2058: ERROR:  type "public.hstore" does not exist
```

But in case I use

```
metadata hstore
```

everything works fine.

Also, have to note that this happens only on our CI where we're running as user `runner` but owner of `public` schema is `postgres`.

If needs some more data, please let me know and I will provide.

Regards,

Comment: Maybe it is already installed in another schema? try `\dx hstore`

Comment: @JGH Yes it turns out that Postgres9.6 includes this extension by default on `pg_catalog` namespace so it's not visible when called with prefix `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if and where the extension is already installed using the command `\dx hstore`

Comment: Thanks again. Wrong location was the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

As we're using Postgres9.3 we have to install hstore manually, on our CI they use Postgres9.6 which automatically add hstore on Db creation.

Also, it puts `hstore` in namespace `pg_catalog` which turned out was the main reason why `hstore` wasn't visible by `public.hstore`.

So what I had to do is to do one step after creating db on CI, which drop particular extension and creates new one in correct schema.

Anyway, the problem wasn't so hard as it was tricky and weird.